# How do I flag a comment I've accidentally upvoted?

Tags: support, comments, flagging, up-votes

I tried to flag a comment, but accidentally upvoted it, and I can't remove the upvote because I have only 1 minute to remove it, which I've only recently discovered.

How do I flag a comment I've accidentally upvoted?

Comment: You can't. And I doubt this is going to be fixed any time soon as it is a corner case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Already been reported, not yet been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-upvoting-it).

In this case the best thing to do is to flag the corresponding post with a custom flag, mentioning that you're unable to flag the comment.